# Why don't all types get expanded?

Tags: haskell, type-level-computation

Suppose

```
type family F (x :: Nat) (y :: Nat) :: (Nat, Nat) where
  F x y = '(x, y)
```

then

```
:t Proxy :: Proxy '[ (F 1 2) ]
Proxy :: Proxy '[ (F 1 2) ] :: Proxy '['(1, 2)]
```

But now suppose

```
type family ZipWith (f :: a -> b -> c) (as :: [a]) (bs :: [b]) :: [c] where
  ZipWith f (a ': as) (b ': bs) = (f a b) ': (ZipWith f as bs)
  ZipWith f as        bs        = '[]

:t Proxy :: Proxy (ZipWith F ('[1,2]) ('[3,4]))
Proxy :: Proxy (ZipWith F ('[1,2]) ('[3,4])) :: Proxy '[F 1 3, F 2 4]
```

Why isn't the type

```
Proxy :: Proxy (ZipWith F ('[1,2]) ('[3,4])) :: Proxy '['(1, 3), '(2, 4)]
```

If I say

```
:t (Proxy :: Proxy (ZipWith F ('[1,2]) ('[3,4]))) :: Proxy '[ '(1, 3), '(2, 4)]
```

then I get a type error

```
    Couldn't match type ‘F’ with ‘'(,)’
Expected type: Proxy (ZipWith F '[1, 2] '[3, 4])
  Actual type: Proxy '['(1, 3), '(2, 4)]
In the expression:
    (Proxy :: Proxy (ZipWith F ('[1, 2]) ('[3, 4]))) ::
      Proxy '['(1, 3), '(2, 4)]
```

But F is '(,) so what's going on? Is this something to do with injectivity?

EDIT in response to the comment which is really an answer:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators         #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables   #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds             #-}
```

Comment: Type synonyms (including type families) cannot be partially applied, like it is in `ZipWith F .. ..`. In fact, I would expect the above to produce an error like `F should have 2 arguments, but has been given none`, and I'm not sure why it doesn't (do you have LiberalTypeSynonyms enabled?). Change `F` to `type family F :: Nat -> Nat -> (Nat, Nat) where F = '(,)` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense and is really an answer which deserves an up vote.